# Is the position of the central peak of a crater on Moon showing that an asteroid hit it while it was not still sinchronised with Earth?

Tags: astrophysics, collision, rotation, moon

Is the position of the central peak of a crater on Moon showing that an asteroid hit it while it was not sinchronised with Earth? If the peak is in very center of the crater and the crater shown on the visible side of the Moon does it tell us that at that time the Moon was still rotating? Because if the impact was at right angle at the center of the visible side then the asteroid should before hitting the Moon pass through Earth. [Link](https://youtu.be/zufx28sBhWg)

Comment: Have a look at this picture of the scale of the Earth, moon, and distance between them, and then imagine your question again: https://imgur.com/gallery/hB9x6kh

Comment: Why big craters have central peaks: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27816/16685

Answer (score 2):

The Earth as seen from the near side of the Moon is about four times wider than the Moon as seen from the Earth. This still takes up a very small amount of the “sky” and still allows plenty of directions from which an object could impact the near side of the Moon.

[Tycho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tycho_(lunar_crater)), which has a prominent central peak, is only about 100 million years old, which is fairly recent in geological terms.